# Как создать номенклатуру 1С УТ 10.3 rest Odata

Tags: 1с, rest

Подскажите как создать элемент номенклатуры в 1С?
Пробую вот так

```
$odata = Yii::$app->connectOdata()->{'Catalog_Номенклатура'}->create([
        'DeletionMark' => false,
        'Predefined' => false,
        'Parent_Key' => 'a3295f70-9e97-11e7-a208-d8c23fcd6071',
        'IsFolder' => false,
        'Code' => '111259',
        'Description' => 'Дисплей (Модуль) для Xiaomi Redmi Note 5A в сборе с тачскрином Белый',
        'СтатьяЗатрат_Key' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        'Артикул' => '111259',
        'БазоваяЕдиницаИзмерения_Key' => '7997a102-9dcd-11e7-a202-3085a93c0618',
        'Весовой' => false,
        'ВесовойКоэффициентВхождения' => '0',
        'ВестиПартионныйУчетПоСериям' => false,
        'ВестиУчетПоСериям' => false,
        'ВестиУчетПоХарактеристикам' => false,
        'ЕдиницаДляОтчетов_Key' => '788beb69-5b00-11e8-883e-3085a93c0618',
        'ЕдиницаХраненияОстатков_Key' => '788beb69-5b00-11e8-883e-3085a93c0618',
        'Комментарий' => '',
        'Набор' => false,
        'НаименованиеПолное' => 'Дисплей (Модуль) для Xiaomi Redmi Note 5A в сборе с тачскрином Белый',
        'НоменклатурнаяГруппа_Key' => '955b01ad-eed1-11e7-8382-3085a93c0618',
        'НомерГТД_Key' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        'ОсновноеИзображение_Key' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        'ОсновнойПоставщик_Key' => 'f7456b69-a74f-11e7-a217-3085a93c0618',
        'ОтветственныйМенеджерЗаПокупки_Key' => 'fdf4bf0a-9cf0-11e7-a201-3085a93c0618',
        'СтавкаНДС' => 'БезНДС',
        'СтранаПроисхождения_Key' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        'Услуга' => false,
        'НоменклатурнаяГруппаЗатрат_Key' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        'ВидНоменклатуры_Key' => '7997a111-9dcd-11e7-a202-3085a93c0618',
        'ВестиСерийныеНомера' => false,
        'Комплект' => false,
        'ЦеноваяГруппа_Key' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        'ЕдиницаИзмеренияМест_Key' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        'ДополнительноеОписаниеНоменклатуры' => '',
        'ДополнительноеОписаниеНоменклатурыВФорматеHTML' => false,
        'АлкогольнаяПродукция' => false,
        'ИмпортнаяАлкогольнаяПродукция' => false,
        'ОбъемДАЛ' => 0,
        'ПроизводительИмпортерАлкогольнойПродукции_Key' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        'ВидАлкогольнойПродукцииЕГАИС_Key' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        'Крепость' => 0,
        'Производитель_Key' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
        'КодТНВЭД_Key' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
    ]);
```

Использую библиотеку https://github.com/kilylabs/odata-1c
Вся загвоздка в том что другие элементы справочника получается создать без особого труда например Catalog_Подразделения или Catalog_ВидыНоменклатуры.

При попытки создать номенклатуру получаю ошибку сервера:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$odata = Yii::$app->connectOdata()->{'Catalog_Номенклатура'}->create([
        'Description' => 'ТЕСТ321',
        'БазоваяЕдиницаИзмерения_Key' => '7997a102-9dcd-11e7-a202-3085a93c0618',
        'ВидНоменклатуры_Key' => '7997a111-9dcd-11e7-a202-3085a93c0618',
    ]);
```

Это обязательные поля для заполнения!